# Too many redirects error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file has 3 Rewrite rules, but I'm facing a redirect issue:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =IP TO BLOCK GOES HERE
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =ANOTHER IP TO BLOCK GOES HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blocked
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myhost.com/blocked [R=307,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=AUTHORIZED IP HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myhost.com/maintenance [R=307,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
```

The problem is if a blocked IP tries do access the site when it is under maintenance, I receive an "Incorrect redirect" error. How to stop Rewrite processing if the IP is one of the denied ips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =IP TO BLOCK GOES HERE
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =ANOTHER IP TO BLOCK GOES HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blocked
RewriteRule ^ http://www.myhost.com/blocked [R=307,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=AUTHORIZED IP HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:maintenance|blocked)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.myhost.com/maintenance [R=307,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this worked, but in the first case, the rule to block IPS, htaccess only gets the first one, the others are ignored, unless I use [OR] operator. Is there a way without using [OR]? Just to be more direct. And why maintenance rule works without adding [OR], but blocked rule not?

Comment: All test are with "and". You need, in this case, to add `[OR]` with more than one `RewriteCond` test. It's possible to add more than one IP in one test: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(111\.111\.111\.111|222\.22\.2\.22|3\.333\.33\.3|xxx\.xx\.xxx\.xx)$`

Comment: Maintenance work without `[OR]` because it's a negative test (with `!`) in this case you can't use [or].

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for the explanation.